# process killed while training

Tags: tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I working on training a machine learning model tend to image processing using GAN algorithm
it has been done on tensorflow backend ,I have split the work on 8 gpus
now when I start my training script It gave the following error

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

any body can crack this
I have been searching a lot and no solution on how to fix this
all I can find that something depending on the lake of memory ...thanks in advance and please inform me for any ambiguity

Comment: Looks like you ran out of RAM. You're probably putting a large dataset into memory instead of reading from disk as training progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone's comment indicates, it looks like you ran out of Memory.  To add to that, the exit code 137 likely means the Out Of Memory Killer killed your process.  There is a good explanation of how it chooses which process to kill [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first) that I often reference.

On your box you can confirm the OOM Killer's involvement by running `dmesg`

To get a sense for how much memory you have available to your processes you can run:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
```

Comment: @Howrad_Roark thanks dear for replying, so it seems the way to solve this is to extend the ram memory

Comment: Well I would look at how much memory is available on your box and then determine whether it makes sense that your process is using that much. Assuming your process is behaving as you expect, then ya adding more memory is the right move

Comment: ok dear, so I have monitored my memory usage with running the script and it seems that it use it all , it is an 8 gig Ram, is there an instruction at tensorflow that preventing the full usage of ram I already have used an instruction to allowing growth of GPU memory, but the problem is within the RAM the memory of the cpu

Answer (score 0):

try using less batch sizes, that might resolve the memory issue.